# cucumber performance & Rail 4 - gem version clashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber

I'm using Rails 4 (4.0.0) for the first time.

I'm not happy with Cucumber's speed.

I did the following:

1. Created the app with `rails new MyApp -T`.
2. Added rspec-rails, cucumber-rails, database_cleaner & therubyracer to the Gemfile, then ran `bundle install`.
3. Ran `rails generate rspec:install` and `rails generate cucumber:install`.

I've not created any models, controllers, view, specs or features. I'm doing double cycle TDD and ran `cucumber` against no features, expecting it to take less than a couple of seconds. I then invoked it with `rake` and `bundle exec` and compared the results (shown below).

`bundle exec cucumber`

```
    noel@noel-U36JC:~/commons/MyApp$ time bundle exec cucumber
    Using the default profile...
    0 scenarios
    0 steps
    0m0.000s

    real    0m22.017s
    user    0m20.749s
    sys     0m1.044s
```

`rake cucumber`

```
    noel@noel-U36JC:~/commons/MyApp$ time rake cucumber
    /home/noel/commons/MyApp/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet. Run `rake db:migrate` 
    to create it, then try again. If you do not intend to use a database, you 
    should instead alter /home/noel/commons/MyApp/config/application.rb to limit 
    the frameworks that will be loaded.

    real    0m18.556s
    user    0m17.329s
    sys     0m1.064s
```

`cucumber`

```
    noel@noel-U36JC:~/commons/MyApp$ time cucumber
    WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
          rake (>= 0.8.7)
          hike (~> 1.2)
          tilt (!= 1.3.0, ~> 1.1)
    WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
    Please report a bug if this causes problems.
    Using the default profile...
    0 scenarios
    0 steps
    0m0.000s

    real    0m19.862s
    user    0m18.681s
    sys     0m1.028s
```

The `Gemfile.lock` has

```
    ...
    hike (1.2.3)
    ...
    rake (10.1.0)
    ...
    tilt (1.4.1)
    ...
```

I haven't been able to find out where Gem::Specification.reset is getting its information from. I've run `gem cleanup` and `gem uninstall`*gemname* and not gotten anywhere with that either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Update: forgot to mention, am running ruby 1.9.3-p484 on RVM. The lappy I'm developing on is 2.5 years old, both ubuntu & RVM have been loaded the whole time, so RVM cruff could be a factor too.

Update (an hour after comment 2):

I tried setting up a new project specific RVM gemset, thinking the cruff in global getset might be the issue.

The setup appeared to work find.

During the `bundle install`, the gem install of rake failed. No joy!

```
    noel@noel-U36JC:~/commons/MyApp$ rvm 1.9.3-p484

    noel@noel-U36JC:~/commons/MyApp$ rvm gemset create MyApp
    gemset created MyApp    => /home/noel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@MyApp

    noel@noel-U36JC:~/commons/MyApp$ rvm --ruby-version use 1.9.3-p484@MyApp
    Using /home/noel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484 with gemset MyApp

    noel@noel-U36JC:~/commons/MyApp$ bundle install
    Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
    Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..

    NoMethodError: private method `open' called for Gem::Package:Class
    An error occured while installing rake (10.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
    Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.

    noel@noel-U36JC:~/commons/MyApp$ gem install rake -v '10.1.0'
    Successfully installed rake-10.1.0
    Installing ri documentation for rake-10.1.0
    1 gem installed

    noel@noel-U36JC:~/commons/MyApp$ bundle install
    Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
    Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..

    NoMethodError: private method `open' called for Gem::Package:Class
    An error occured while installing rake (10.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
    Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.

    noel@noel-U36JC:~/commons/MyApp$ time cucumber
    The program 'cucumber' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
    sudo apt-get install cucumber

    real    0m0.126s
    user    0m0.064s        
    sys     0m0.056s
```

Update:

Looks to be a Bundler version issue.

Bundler version was 1.1.3.

Is now 1.3.5.

```
    noel@noel-U36JC:~/commons/MyApp$ time cucumber
    Using the default profile...
    0 scenarios
    0 steps
    0m0.000s

    real    0m6.926s
    user    0m6.592s
    sys 0m0.280s
```

Well that appears to have worked. :)

Comment: I ignore this problem when I see it - it says its clearing itself up and it does.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. How often did you have to rerun it, before it fixed itself. I've run is a few dozen time so far. Initially there were about a dozen in the list, `gem cleanup` fixed up all but these three. How much time elapsed before it cleared itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a Bunder version issue

So the solution was:

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

Final cucumber timing was 6 to 7 seconds, down from initial 60 seconds plus.